# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.avada.rest.UsersController$Users]

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am getting the following exception and not sure why...

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [class com.avada.rest.UsersController$Users] and content type
>   [application/json;charset=UTF-8]  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:576)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:236)
>     at com.avada.rest.UsersTest.main(UsersTest.java:18)

This is my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Users getUsers() {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setUsers(ConstantsHome.userprofileMgr.getUsers(null));
        return users;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        return ConstantsHome.userprofileMgr.getUserByUserId(id, true, true);
    }

    public static class Users {
        private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<User> getUsers() {
            return users;
        }

        public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
            this.users = users;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Test class:

```
public class UsersTest {
    private static RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Get all users
        String uri = "http://localhost:8080/IR360/rest/users";
        UsersController.Users users = template.getForObject(uri, UsersController.Users.class);
        System.out.println("Looping through users...");
        for (User user : users.getUsers()) {
            System.out.println("Name=" + user.getName());
        }

        // Get 1 user
        uri = "http://localhost:8080/IR360/rest/users/admin";
        User user = template.getForObject(uri, User.class);
        System.out.println("Name for single user=" + user.getName());
    }
}
```

I can get a single user no problem if I comment out the test code for "Get all users".

What am I doing wrong in this code?

P.S. - I can make a call to `getUsers()` through the browser and the json comes back fine so I know `getUsers()` is working...just can't get the `RestTemplate` to work

Comment: Add an instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to your `RestTemplate`'s list of converters during construction

Comment: All of the following converters are present in my `RestTemplate`: 0 = {ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@1366} 
1 = {StringHttpMessageConverter@1367} 
2 = {ResourceHttpMessageConverter@1368} 
3 = {SourceHttpMessageConverter@1369} 
4 = {AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@1370} 
5 = {Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter@1371} 
6 = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1372}

Comment: can you post your `Users` class

Comment: @Jaiwo99 - I've been researching and it looks like my `User` class is indeed the issue - it's a big monster.  Is there a way to make Jackson more lenient in it's serialization/deserialization?  I guess I could also modify the `User` class to be a solid POJO that Jackson can handle

Comment: yes, sure, you can.. like @JsonIgnore or so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue in my `Users` class (more specifically the `User` class in `List<User>`).

I updated the `User` class with `@JsonIgnore` on fields that I thought might be causing the Exception and I was able to get passed this issue.

So for others that might encounter this issue, check the object you're trying to do a `getForObject` on to make sure everything can map fine.